# Hector query for all data in a column family

Tags: cassandra, hector

I want to write a code using hector api that bring me result some thing like i got `select * from table`
is it possible in Cassandra.please reply as soon as possible

Comment: Depends how is structured the ColumnFamily

Answer (score 2):

Depends how is structured the ColumnFamily

A example using columSlice and StringSerializer could be:

```
ColumnSlice<String, String> result = HFactory.createSliceQuery(ksp, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer)
            .setKey(row)
            .setRange(startColumn, endColumn, false, limit)
            .setColumnFamily(columnFamily)
            .execute().get();

    List<HColumn<String, String>> columns = result.getColumns();
```

Answer (score 0):

SliceQuery will not give all the rows in a columnfamily as it requires a row key. To fetch all the rows of a column family use rangeSliceQuery with null in keys and range

```
RangeSlicesQuery<Object, Object, Object> rangeQuery =    HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, keySerializer,
            nameSerializer, valueSerializer);
rangeQuery.setColumnFamily(cf);
rangeQuery.setRange(null, null, false, MAX_COL);
rangeQuery.setKeys(null, null);
rangeQuery.setRowCount(rowCount);//Greater than count(*)
QueryResult<OrderedRows<Object, Object, Object>> result = rangeQuery.execute();
```